# matriz de mapas dentro de otra matriz

Tags: javascript, matrix

I have the following array:

```
const array = [
        {array2: [{price: 3000}, {price: 2000}, {price: 0}]},
        {array2: [{price: 1000}, {price: 0}, {price: 6000}]}
    ];
```

what I need to do a filter to each of the array2, I have been trying this but it does not work for me

```
array.forEach(e => {
        e.array2.filter(p => p.price > 0)
    });
```

when putting the console.log () of the array, it keeps showing me the normal array, while it should show me the array2 filtered by those with the price greater than 0.

Any help I will appreciate, thank you very much.

updated array:

```
const array = [
        {
          array2: [{price: 3000}, {price: 2000}, {price: 0}],
          name: 'apple',
          id: 1
        },
        {
          array2: [{price: 1000}, {price: 0}, {price: 6000}],
          name: 'banana',
          id: 2
        }
      ];
```

Comment: `filter()` does not modify an array, but returns a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Sirko already commented `filter` doesn't modify an array instead it returns a new one.

```js
const array = [
  { array2: [{ price: 3000 }, { price: 2000 }, { price: 0 }] },
  { array2: [{ price: 1000 }, { price: 0 }, { price: 6000 }] },
];

const result = array.map(({ array2 }) => {
  return { array2: array2.filter((o) => o.price > 0) };
});

console.log(result);
```

If there are multiple properties in an object then you need to do this

```js
const array = [
  { test: 123, array2: [{ price: 3000 }, { price: 2000 }, { price: 0 }] },
  { test2: 234, array2: [{ price: 1000 }, { price: 0 }, { price: 6000 }] },
];

const result = array.map((obj) => {
  return { ...obj, array2: obj.array2.filter((o) => o.price > 0) };
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi Sam, this works correctly, but it is not what I expected, since it only returns the array2, I feel that within the array there are more attributes within the object, so I expected it to return exactly the same, but with the filtered array2

Comment: It is what you've asked so if you need something more then it would be better to add your code in codesandbox or jsfiddle. Then I can help you. Because it is not clear what exactly do you want...

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the code to store the filtered array

```
array.forEach((e) => {
  let modifiedArray = e.array2.filter((p) => p.price > 0);
  console.log(modifiedArray);
});
```

OUTPUT

```
[ { price: 3000 }, { price: 2000 } ]
[ { price: 1000 }, { price: 6000 } ]
```